Challenge with Circular Repeat
I'm trying to solve this JavaScript test:

Given a string s and a number n, return a new string with the characters of s repeated n times consecutively in a circular manner. If the length of the new string is greater than 100, truncate it to a length of 100.

So far, I've tried these options:
function circularRepeat(s, n) {
    n = Math.min(n, 100); // Ensure n doesn't exceed 100

  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    result += s[i % s.length]; // Use modulo to select characters circularly
  }
  return result;
}

function circularRepeat(s, n) {
    return n > 100 ? s.repeat(100) : s.repeat(n);
}

They all fail though:

What's wrong here? how can it be solved?

Do you know what input the first solution fails on?

not sure if I understood correctly, lets say your string is a 9 character word calculate so If the value of s is that and the value of n is 10. Then that means my result should be calculatec or calculatecalculate???

The instructions are really unclear, but they might have meant i < Math.min(n * s.length, 100)

You will need to calculate: n / len(s) to determine how many times to repeat. After that, you just strap on the remainder substring at the end.


function circularRepeat1(s, n) {
  n = Math.min(n, 100); // Ensure n doesn't exceed 100
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    result += s[i % s.length]; // Use modulo to select characters circularly
  }
  return result;
}

function circularRepeat2(s, n) {
  n = Math.min(n, 100);
  const repeatTimes = Math.floor(n / s.length);
  return s.repeat(repeatTimes) + s.slice(0, n % s.length);
}

// Should print true for all cases
for (let n of [50, 100, 200]) {
  console.log(circularRepeat1('foobar', n) === circularRepeat2('foobar', n));
}




This is not what the challenge is after (which became clear with the OP's edit)

s.repeat(...).slice(...) is naive as large n produce large strings, where all but the first 100 chars are thrown. Allocate an array with only the number of elements you will need, then finally join the elements to produce the output string -


function circularRepeat(s, n, maxlen = 100) {
  const a = Array(Math.max(0, Math.min(n, maxlen)))
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) a[i] = s[i % s.length]
  return a.join("")
}

console.log(circularRepeat("foobar", 2))        // length: 2
console.log(circularRepeat("foobar", 40))       // length: 40
console.log(circularRepeat("foobar", 600))      // length: 100
console.log(circularRepeat("foobar", 600, 555)) // length: 555



Here's a recursive implementation -


const circularRepeat = (s = "", min = 0, max = 100, z = Math.min(min, max)) =>
  z <= 0
    ? ""
    : s.length > z
      ? s.slice(0, Math.max(0, z))
      : s + circularRepeat(s, min, max, z - s.length)

console.log(circularRepeat("foobar", 2))        // length: 2
console.log(circularRepeat("foobar", 40))       // length: 40
console.log(circularRepeat("foobar", 600))      // length: 100
console.log(circularRepeat("foobar", 600, 555)) // length: 555




The instructions are a bit ambiguous, it's not clear whether n refers to the number of characters to be generated or to the number of repetitions of the input string s. The expected output does however clarify that they meant the latter.
Your first attempt did repeat up to Math.min(n, 100) characters, following the former (wrong) interpretation.
Your second attempt did repeat the whole string n times, but did limit the number of repetitions to 100 instead of "the length of the new string".
The correct solution would be
function circularRepeat(s, n) {
    return s.repeat(n).slice(0, 100);
}

or
function circularRepeat(s, n) {
  const l = Math.min(n * s.length, 100);

  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    result += s[i % s.length]; // Use modulo to select characters circularly
  }
  return result;
}

